# Is it possible to find table list that meets criteria for last row of tables?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have lots of tables in an SQLite database that all share the same table name structure. e.g. ONE_data, TWO_data, THREE_data, ..., N_data. All of these tables share the same column structure, as well. e.g. radius REAL, theta REAL, phi REAL - (polar coordinates). I interact with this database via Python with the sqlite3 library version 3.38.3.

Is there a way to query the database to retrieve a list of tables where the last data row fits certain criteria? Something like:

SELECT table_name FROM schema WHERE radius > i, theta > j, phi < k

I already have a loop that steps through each table and queries the last data row, does the logic check, and then adds the table name to a list if it fits the criteria. When there were only a few hundred tables it wasn't an issue, but now I have thousands of tables that are tracking the historical location of thousands of unique objects it's time expensive and it would be nice to speed it up.

Comment: How do you define the "last row" of a table?

Comment: If you are handling that big a dataset, maybe you should switch to a more powerful DB.

Comment: This is a really poor design. Dynamic information should be in table data, not table names. There's no way to join with table names.

Comment: you should keep all data in one table and use extra column with name